# Why is $http.get() undefined in my Angular service?

Tags: json, angularjs, service, rootscope

I'm trying to load some JSON and store it using $rootScope so that it persists between controllers. When I run my app I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

The get method was working perfectly until I tried to introduce $rootScope... any ideas?

My service looks like this:

```
  1 /**
  2  * Service to get the quiz data from a JSON source
  3  */
  4 app.factory('quizService', ['$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
  5     var promise;
  6     var service = {
  7         getQuiz: function($scope, $http) {
  8             if ( !promise ) {
  9                 promise = $http.get('QuizFileName.quiz').then(function (response) {
 10                     return response.data;
 11                 });
 12             }
 13             return promise;
 14         }
 15     };
 16     return service;
 17 }]);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  7     // Get Quiz data from service
  8     quizService.getQuiz().then(function(data) {
  9         $scope.quiz = data;
 10
 11         // Redirect to scores if already completed this
 12         if($scope.quiz.complete === true) {
 13             $location.path('scores');
 14         }
 15     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Reboog711 put me on the right track, I needed to modify my factory definition to include $http, I had previously tried to do this, but mistakenly put it together like this:

```
'$rootScope, $http'
```

Don't do this, it's bad and wrong! But Reboog711's answer also gave me errors because I think you can't use $scope in the way we both thought.

The correct (or working) solution was:

```
app.factory('quizService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
```

I hope this helps other newcomers to Angular. Many thanks to all who replied with their comments. I really respect this community for its great attitude to helping others :)

Answer (score 7):

You are using the 'array pattern' in defining your factory. You should have a string for each of the services you use in your function, but you only have one.

That is, what you do is

```
app.factory('quizService', ['$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    //insert code
}]);
```

but what you should do is

```
app.factory('quizService', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    //insert code
}]);
```

AngularJS will map the functions named with the strings to the parameters. Try that and see if it fixes your issue.

**EDIT**: Ah,the answer from Reboog711 makes more sense in solving the issue, I somehow missed the latter part of the code. But I'm leaving this answer in since you should also fix the factory definition.

Comment: +! for catching the problem w/ array notation problem.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative to the array pattern to defining factories?

Comment: I personally use this pattern everytime I write angular code, since it is designed to survive minification. I would personally recommend you keep using it. What is happening is that after minification, you might end up with `app.factory('quizService', ['$http', function (a) { .. }]);` since minification will reduce variables to as few characters as possible. Strings are not changed so angular checks the first string and knows that the variable `a` is actually `$http`.

Answer (score 3):

getQuiz is a function inside a factory:

```
getQuiz: function($scope, $http) {
```

When you call the getQuiz, you do not pass any arguments into it:

```
quizService.getQuiz()
```

$http is undefined because you call it without passing any arguments into it.  Angular will not inject items into a function that you call manually.  It will only do so with functions that AngularJS calls itself--such as controller or factory functions.

So, you have a few options.  One is to pass the $scope and $http arguments into the function, like this:

```
quizService.getQuiz($scope, $http)
```

I'm sure this would solve the issue, but it would be a weird approach for sure.

I would probably remove the $scope and $http functions out of the function definition:

```
 getQuiz: function() {
```

Then make sure that you modify your factory definition:

```
app.factory('quizService', ['$scope','$rootScope','$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
```

Without this modification, the Angular services will not be passed into your function.

Then, when you access $http inside the function, it should access the value passed into the factory which should not be undefined.

Comment: I'm so annoyed with myself for missing this! You are right that I needed to add $http to the definition.