# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror

```
$http.get('/contactList').
success(function(data){
    console.log('got http get');
}).
error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.data = data;
    return 'error name';
});
```

I have an error with just this section of code. I am trying to use the `$http.get` function with Angular JS. Am I doing something wrong?

I keep getting an error.

Comment: Did you properly add your dependencies?  See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Can you edit to show where you declare your controller?

Comment: most probably he is injecting the `$http` if not the error should be `$http is not defined` instead of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.

Comment: Are you *minifying* your code?

Comment: Can you show the controller code please? It's tough to pin point the error cause w/o it.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376087/why-is-http-get-undefined-in-my-angular-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters said you should look at your controller declaration, you need to 'inject' the $http service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('messageController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get()
  .success()
  .error();
}]);
```

Comment: angular.module('App',[])




.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope',function($scope,$http){

 console.log("Hello world from controller");

 $http.get('/contactList').success(function(data){
   console.log('got http get');

 }).
  error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.data = data;

    return 'error name';
  });

Answer (score 1):

As I do not see any controller code, I would have to assume one out of the following could be causing this issue,

1. You don't have all the dependencies injected in your controller as the commentators and @Plato has pointed out. Check this -> [TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376087/why-is-http-get-undefined-in-my-angular-service)
2. You have injected all the dependencies but do not match the order, e.g., what should be `['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)`, you would have mentioned like this `['$scope', '$http', function($http, $scope)`. When using the array notation for injecting dependencies, the order of the arguments is important. Check this -> [AngularJS $http.get returns undefined and $http() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123589/angularjs-http-get-returns-undefined-and-http-is-not-a-function)