# Ionic Storage : TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

I'm using Ionic Storage to store data on the long run. Right now i wanna retrieve data when i go to the Statistics page, so i called the Service i made and wrote the methods in the ngOnInit of the statistics page but it doesn't recognize the instanciation of the storage class if i understood the issue correctly but the weird thing is that it does work when i write the methods in the ionViewWillEnter(). I made both ngOnInit and ionViewWillEnter async but i still get an error for the ngOnInit. I could go with the ionViewWillEnter trick if i'm not wrong it is similar to calling the methods in ngOnInit in my use case but i'm still curious of why it gets me errors...

TS of the statistics page :

```
import { StatsService } from './../service/stats.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-statistics',
  templateUrl: './statistics.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./statistics.page.scss'],
})
export class StatisticsPage implements OnInit {

  testsAmount: any = 0;

  constructor(public statsService: StatsService) {}

  addJohn(){
    this.statsService.set("1", "john");
  }

  removeAll(){
    this.statsService.clearAll();
  }

  async getJohn(){
    console.log(await this.statsService.get("1"));
  }

  

  async ngOnInit() {
      await this.statsService.set("testSetngOnInit", "blabla");
      console.log("testSet initialized from the ngOnInit");
      console.log(await this.statsService.get("testSetngOnInit"));
  }

  async ionViewWillEnter(){
    await this.statsService.set("testSetionViewWillEnter", "blabla");
      console.log("testSet initialized from the ionViewWillEnter");
    console.log(await this.statsService.get("testSetionViewWillEnter"));
  }

  

}
```

TS of the Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import * as CordovaSQLiteDriver from 'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StatsService {
  
  // private _storage: Storage | null = null;
  private _storage: Storage;

  constructor(public storage: Storage) { 
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    // If using, define drivers here: await this.storage.defineDriver(/*...*/);
    await this.storage.defineDriver(CordovaSQLiteDriver);
    const storage = await this.storage.create();
    this._storage = storage;
  }

  async keyExistence(key: string){
    if(await this.get(key) == null){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }

  // Create and expose methods that users of this service can
  // call, for example:
  async set(key: string, value: any) {
    await this._storage?.set(key, value);
  }

  async clearAll() {
    await this._storage.clear();
  }

  async get(key: string) {
    return await this._storage.get(key);
  }

}
```

And this is what i get in the console :
[image: console]

And my IndexDB :

[image: IndexDB]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250682/typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined)

Comment: Not really, Angular doesn't use the same syntax as AgularJS. In the post you sent they had a problem on the whole instanciation when in my case it only has an error when i try to use it inside the ngOnInit

Comment: This error is not an angular error, it's not a typescript error,  It's not a ionic framework error, it's a Javascript error.  It's literally the same the error, you are calling method or property on an variable that has a value of undefined.

Comment: I'm aware of the nature of the issue but i'm just not able to tell why. Matt sugested earlier that it could be a timing issue, but in that case i don't know how to tell ngOnInit to wait for the Service instanciation because from what i understand the ngOnInit doesn't wait for the constructor to finish the process but for some reason the constructor makes it in time for the ionViewWillEnter to be able to use it...
Well, it looks like you might have understood the issue better than me, could you indicate me where i could work on something to solve my issue ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer ! This is actually very simple to solve, so stupid that I didn't think about it...
So instead of instanciating the service in its own class, you have to instanciate it in the class where you use it, so in my case :

What I had in the service constructor :

```
constructor(public storage: Storage) { 
    this.init();
  }
```

But the thing is the constructor cannot use the async statement so you can't tell your class to wait for it, so what you need is to init inside the ngOnInit of the class using it :

My page using the service :

```
async ngOnInit() {
      await this.statsService.init();
  }
```

Hope this would help some people :)

Comment: Hi, I have the same set up as above, although i am missing this part " await this.storage.defineDriver(CordovaSQLiteDriver);" as i am using capacitor in my ionic angular app. I dont understand why my data in storage gets deleleted after page refresh.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if you're using Cordova or Capacitor, according to the ionic doc, this is the only difference :
# If using Cordova, install the plugin using 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
# If using Capacitor, install the plugin using
npm install cordova-sqlite-storage
So even tho you're using Capacitor, you can use it. What is weird is that you're testing the app in your browser right now i believe and browsers use indexDB instead of SQLite.
Are you sure that you configured correctly the whole thing ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that line 44 in stats.service.ts is the line which caused the issue. Your component `ngOnInit` is indeed accessing the service instance, but the service itself is failing. I imagine this is because your constructor for `StatsService` is calling `this.init();`, but the constructor is not awaiting it (and I don't think it can). Thus when you try to access it that early (in ngOnInit) `this._storage` has not yet been initialized.

The reason `statsService.set` appears to succeed is because that method calls `this._storage?.set(key, value)` - note the `?` which is a null conditional, meaning if `_storage` is null then the whole expression evaluates as `null`.

I don't know for sure, but I assume `ionViewWillEnter` is called later in the component lifecycle, and the stats service constructor has had enough time to fully initialize. On the other hand, `ngOnInit` is called right after the component constructor.

Comment: Yeah you're right, getting rid of the "?" brings an error on the set instead. Seems like the storage is instancied after the ngOnInit is finalized (then before the Service is even instancied ? which is weird). Like you said we can't put an async/await on the constructor so i don't really know whick track i should inverstigate

Answer (score 0):

**Call init in your AppComponent to create an instance of storage. and this should called only one time.**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit,{

  constructor(
    private storage: StorageService
    ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.storage.init();
}
```